# Are ICAO and FAA airport signs and markings the same?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport, runways, icao-sarps

Are ICAO and FAA airport signs and markings the same or are there differences? If so what are the differences?

Comment: [Here are the FAA sign standards](https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/news/publications/media/QuickReferenceGuideProof8.pdf)

Comment: This question seems very broad. The full list of airport signs and markings is extensive; if the answer is *NO*—they are not the same—then an exhaustive comparison would likely be too broad for this exchange. I am not voting to close, as yet, but I think you would do well to narrow your question's scope, for example to certain signage, or to runway markings.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was hoping to find something similar to this but for ICAO ... https://www.faa.gov/airports/runway_safety/news/publications/media/QuickReferenceGuideProof8.pdf

Comment: Reference [this Jeppesen document](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/airport-signs.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

**Principle**

ICAO Airport markings are defined by ICAO in [Annex 14](http://www.icao.int/safety/implementation/library/manual%20aerodrome%20stds.pdf) of Chicago Convention, *Aerodromes*.

ICAO also requires at section 5.8 *Notification of differences in the AIP* of [Doc 8126](http://www2010.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2014/ECARAIM/REF09-Doc8126.pdf) *Aeronautical Information Services Manual*, that differences are explained in the country AIP, Section GEN 1.7 *Differences from ICAO Standards, Recommended Practices and Procedures*.

US regulations are not entirely compliant with ICAO SARP, and differences exist for airport marking.

**Example of ICAO SARP**

For the touchdown zone lights, ICAO states in Annex 14, at paragraph 5.3.13.2:

> The lateral  spacing between the innermost lights of a pair of
>   barrettes shall be equal to the lateral spacing selected for the
>   touchdown zone  marking. The longitudinal spacing between pairs of
>   barrettes shall be either 30 m or 60 m.

**US example**

As US regulations are not fully compliant, the differences are explained in [GEN 1.7](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIP.pdf) of the US AIP, page 129:

> U.S. does not require the lateral spacing of touchdown zone lights
>   to be equal to that of touchdown zone marking when runways are less
>   that 45 meters wide.

**In general**

All differences can be found at this location, sorted by ICAO reference and chapter. Differences related to Annex 14 start on page 124 (actually labeled *GEN 1.7 81*). Listing all of them (15 pages in the AIP) would be too broad for this answer.