# Do runway markings vary from country to country?

Tags: runways, airport-markings

I understand that most of the airports should follow FAA/ICAO for runway markings but most of the countries have their own standardization orgs. So, how much do the runway markings vary from USA to Europe?

Edit: We are mainly looking for the big commercial airplanes and not the smaller and private strips which handles only big jets for commercial operations.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25360/62)

Comment: In my part of the U.S. there are numerous grass/gravel strips that have no markings as well as some paved runways that have no markings.

Comment: Thanks but We are mainly looking for the big commercial airplanes and not the smaller and private strips which handles only big jets for commercial operations. Question edited to be specific.

Answer (score 2):

**Do runway markings vary from country to country?**

Yes, examples are [touchdown zone markings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30658/14897) and [runway number sizes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35366/14897).

**How much do the runway markings vary from USA to Europe?**

Europe is too big to manually check each country, but it doesn't vary by much. Numbers are still numbers and TDZ markings still follow the same pattern.

Even smaller airports, say in the US, don't necessarily match bigger airports.

Difference are submitted to ICAO to be included in supplements to Annex 14 when it comes to international airports (typically). And each country's AIP will list the differences from ICAO Annex 14. So if you are interested in a certain country, check its AIP. If interested in the recommended standards, check Annex 14.